# Use "arithmetic shift right" as "less than zero"

Tags: floating-point, cpu-architecture, sse, avx, avx2

Is the following:

```
psrad xmm0, 31        ; arithmetic (sign-extend) shift right
```

equivalent to:

```
xorps xmm1, xmm1      ; zero
cmpps xmm0, xmm1, 1   ; less than
```

I am interested to know, because the shift instruction has lower latency (1 instead of usually 4), at least on Intel chips (somehow [a certain table](https://uops.info/table.html) says that Zen `cmpps` has latency 1).

Are there any reasons not to use the shift instruction?

I suppose `psrad` will not handle NaNs correctly and maybe will not raise floating point exceptions? (Not that this is a huge concern).

I have heard that switching between floating point and integer operations (still on simd unit) can have an impact, but never could verify that. Would that be a concern?

Comment: NaNs will be wrong, definitely, and indeed, `psrad` never raises numeric exceptions.  Another difference is that `-0.0 < +0.0` should be false, but your `psrad` test will tell you it is true.

Comment: I guess it also won't respect the denormals-are-zero flag.

Comment: Yes, but the argument would be flushed to zero by the previous instruction :D

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result? If you want to take it as argument for a `blendvps` you don't need the shift at all. If you want to `ptest` it, just `ptest` with a `0x80000000` mask. (Both assuming, you actually only care for the sign-bit not for NaN or +-0.0 behavior)

Comment: @chtz Oh wow) I thought `blendvps` behaves like poor man's blend with ands and ors. Still the full mask is useful sometimes.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It treats `-0.0` as negative, so it simply has different semantics from IEEE FP compares, assuming that underflow to -0.0 was originally negative.  Sometimes that's fine, like after multiplication by a small number.  It treats negative denormals the same as negative zero, so even if the FP value came from a thread running with FTZ so it was -0.0 instead of subnormal, you'd still get an underflowed value treated as zero,  (beothunder: FTZ and DAZ are separate bits, although usually you use neither or both.)

Comment: I've used `andps` to implement boolean conditions on float compares without actually doing the comparison, just an FMA or sub result, for significant speedups from avoiding the compare instructions in a points-in-polygon check.  (And `xorps` to accumulate odd/even).  It worked fine to treat -0.0 as negative, and -NaN was something we didn't care about.  I was producing a bitmap for later intersection and use with other data, otherwise I would `blendvps` using the sign bit instead of psrad to get a mask.  Do you have a use-case for the mask in mind?  Like blend without SSE4.1?